# Mocked service in component still demands HttpClient as provider

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a component which uses a mockService. I created as such.

NOTE: For this question I altered the name, in the project it has a more specific name.

**list.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('ListComponent', () => {
  let component: ListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ListComponent>;
  let ITEMS: ListItem[];
  let mockService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    ITEMS = require('../../../../../assets/mockdata/items.json');
    mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getItems']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [NoopAnimationsModule, RouterTestingModule, SharedModule],
      declarations: [ListComponent, SomePipe, AnotherPipe],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: Service,
          useValue: mockService,
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TimesheetListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    mockService.getItems.and.returnValue(of(ITEMS));
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  describe('regular behavior', () => {
    it('should create', () => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

**list.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss'],
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  // left out props;

  constructor(private service: Service, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    // This forces the page to reload to the default queryparams when no queryparams are given.
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function() {
      return false;
    };
  }
```

This gives the following error:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[Service -> HttpClient]:
          StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Service -> HttpClient]:
            NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
```

I have a completely different component (`DetailComponent`) also using this `Service` but it doesn't complain about anything.

I should not provide HttpClient because list.component.ts doesn't have a dependency on that component, the service has this and I tested that code separately.

I'm really baffled, maybe I'm looking over something or? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Provide the `@Component` section of the problematic component please

Comment: I already did, if I need to provide MORE information, then sure. I'm not sure what parts are relevant for this issue.

Comment: My apologies, I provided this section, not sure if it helps.

Comment: Does the unit under test itself instantiate any child components? If there are children that inject services for http requests, you will get this error. You can get around this by either adding `schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` to the test bed setup, or by mocking the service(s) injected into the child.

Comment: Thanks @TheHeadRush, this is the solution. The CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA didn't work for me, but I decided to use `ng-mocks` and mock the child component so I don't have to declare input/outputs manually. Thanks for giving me the solution! If you would make it answer instead of an comment I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can arise when testing a component that instantiates a child component which also injects a service using `HttpClient`.

To illustrate, consider the following components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent-component',
  template: `<app-child-component></app-child-component>`
})
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private service: FooService) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-component',
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(private service: BarService) { }
}
```

Assume that both `FooService` and `BarService` inject `HttpClient`.

Following the documentation, a test set up for `ParentComponent` might look something like:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  const mockService = jasmine.createSpyObject(['fooMethod']);
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ParentComponent],
    providers: [
      {
        provide: FooService,
        useValue: mockService,
      },
    ],
  }).compileComponents();
}));
```

However, when `angular` instantiates the `ParentComponent` it also instantiates `ChildComponent`, which needs to inject `BarService`. Since you haven't told `TestBed` to provide a mock, it provides the actual service which, in turn, depends on `HttpClient`.

There are a number of solutions. If you want to test the integration of `ParentComponent` and `ChildComponent`, the simplest thing to do is to tell `TestBed` to mock the `BarService` required by the child. If you want to maintain a strict unit test you can either provide a mocked child component that does not inject an `HttpClient` service to `TestBed`:

```
@Component {(
  selector: 'app-child-component'
)}
export class MockChildComponent {
  constructor() { }
}
```

and set up the test as follows:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ParentComponent, ChildComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: Service,
      useValue: mockService,
    },
  ],
}).compileComponents();
```

Or you can override the component instantiation by telling `TestBed` to use the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ParentComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: Service,
      useValue: mockService,
    },
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
}).compileComponents();
```

Comment: The last part I didn't know, what I did was, declare the ChildComponent AND add the custom_elements_schema, apparently you can't do that.

I choose to mock the child component with ng-mocks.

Thanks a lot @TheHeadRush.